# Program for Internet Service Provider

Tags: python

I am writing an internet service provider program. My problem with the code is that it is not printing the monthly bill correctly.

For example:
If the user enters package "A" and num of hours used (say 9 hrs)
Then it should print 9.95 when the function printBill is called

My question: How can I call the data from getPackage() to the function printBill()

```
#Bill for Package A
def getPackageA(hours):
    if (hours < 10):
        return 9.95 #Cost of Package A
    else:
        return (hours-10)*2 + 9.95

#Bill for Package B
def getPackageB(hours):
    if (hours < 20):
        return 13.95 #Cost of Package B
    else:
        return (hours - 20) + 13.95

#Bill for Package C
def getPackageC():
    return 19.95 #Cost of Package C

#Print Bill and savings
def printBill(bill):
    if (bill != 0):
        print("Your monthly bill is $", format(bill, '.2f'), 
        sep = '')
        getSavings(bill)
        print()
        print()
    else:
        print()


#Checks and display savings if applicable
def getSavings(bill):
    if(bill > getPackageA(hours)):
        print("If you had package A, you'd save $",\
            format(bill - getPackageA(hours),'.2f'), sep = 
            '')
    if(bill > getPackageB(hours)):
        print("If you had package B, you'd save $",\
            format(bill - getPackageB(hours),'.2f'), sep = 
            '')
    if(bill > getPackageC()):
        print("If you had package C, you'd save $",\
              format(bill - getPackageC(), '.2f'), sep = '')

def main():
    bill = 1
    #Asks user to enter choice of package and hours used
    packageChoice = str(input("Enter package purchased (A, 
    B, or C): "))
    hours = int(input("Enter the number of hours used: "))

    if(packageChoice == 'A' or packageChoice == 'a'):
        getPackageA(hours)
    elif (packageChoice == 'B' or packageChoice == 'b'):
        getPackageB(hours)
    elif (packageChoice == 'C' or packageChoice == 'c'):
        getPackageC()
    else:
        print("Package choice must be A, B, or C.")

    printBill(bill)

main()
```

Comment: "getSavings(bill)" has the variable hours in it yet you haven't defined what hours is? As mentioend below, pass all the variables you need into your function, def myfunc(input1, input2, input3,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass hours to every function that needs to use it, also when you RETURN something, it needs a place to get returned to. So you were saying if hours were < 10, return 9.95, but when you say return it sends the code back to the place it got called, you didnt assign this to a variable, so bill defaults to $1. Here is the updated code to work

```
    #Bill for Package A
def getPackageA(hours):
    if hours < 10:
        return 9.95 #Cost of Package A
    else:
        return (hours-10)*2 + 9.95


#Bill for Package B
def getPackageB(hours):
    if hours < 20:
        return 13.95 #Cost of Package B
    else:
        return (hours - 20) + 13.95


#Bill for Package C
def getPackageC():
    return 19.95 #Cost of Package C


#Print Bill and savings
def printBill(bill, hours):
    if (bill != 0):
        print("Your monthly bill is $", format(bill, '.2f'), sep='')
        getSavings(bill, hours)
        print('\n')


#Checks and display savings if applicable
def getSavings(bill, hours):
    if bill > getPackageA(hours):
        print("If you had package A, you'd save $",\
            format(bill - getPackageA(hours),'.2f'), sep='')
    if bill > getPackageB(hours):
        print("If you had package B, you'd save $",\
            format(bill - getPackageB(hours),'.2f'), sep='')
    if bill > getPackageC():
        print("If you had package C, you'd save $",\
              format(bill - getPackageC(), '.2f'), sep='')


def main():
    bill = 1
    #Asks user to enter choice of package and hours used
    packageChoice = str(input("Enter package purchased (A, B, or C): "))
    hours = int(input("Enter the number of hours used: "))

    if packageChoice in ('a', 'A') :
        bill = getPackageA(hours)
    elif packageChoice.lower() == 'b':
        bill = getPackageB(hours)
    elif packageChoice.upper() == 'C':
        bill = getPackageC()
    else:
        print("Package choice must be A, B, or C.")

    printBill(bill, hours)


main()
```

I also edited your main() function to show you different ways to check responses. You also don't need to wrap things in brackets in Python in IF statements.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in multiple parameters to a function.

```
def printBill(bill)
```

becomes:

```
def printBill(bill,hours):
```

and you call it with:

```
printBill(bill,hours)
```

You will also have to pass it to getSavings in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can simply do:

```
bill = 1
bill += getPackage()  # call function and add return value to total bill
printBill(bill)
```